# jsp html image marquee from server image folder

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, marquee

I would like to make a moving image marquee( or slider) on my webpage that displays images stored in the /images folder in server-side machine.I have no idea of jQuery.I am using jsp,html,javascript.I guess Ajax will be required too, but I have very basic idea of Ajax.

Comment: Have a look at blog-post - jQuery marquee - http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Comment: I feel ajax is not required. But make sure Before the page loads all the images should be available.

Comment: I think I mentioned about image marquee, not text!!and the images are stored in server-side folder.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is definitely the way to go. There are hundreds of image gallery plugins, some of which should suit your needs. 
I googled for something to fit your description but finding the perfect solution would take a while. Here's an example of what you could customize: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html

Do a little research and you'll come up with the right thing. Please, make sure to check the license before using any plugin. Some of them are freebies but their use is limited.

As for ajax... I'm pretty sure you can do without it. Just load all images you need along with the entire page and use JavaScript to fiddle with their visibility.